# Replace cartridge of valve for shower

Tags: plumbing

I have some problem with my shower, the control of cold and hot water doesnt work. My guess is that the cartridge of the valve needs to be replaced. The problem is that I dont know the brand for the faucet.

I have the photo attached (the upper handle is the one that controls volume, the lower handle is the one that controls the temperature. ), any suggestion is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have shut off valves built in (second picture) the flat head screws on either side of the lower handle. you can shut them off and remove the cartridge to take it to a plumbing supply and they should be able to tell you.

Looking at the 2nd photo, it appears that the hot side is shut off or at least partially shut off. Try opening the valve and see if that helps.